# Inserting data in Many-to-Many relationship (intermediate table) via MS Access linked to SQL server database

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I have a contact database, created on SQL server. An example of its many to many relationships is below:

```
1- Contact table (ContactID, Fname, Lname, ...)
2-Contact_Skill table (ContactID, SkillID, Score)
3-Skill table (SkillID, Skill_name, Skill_type)
```

For easier interaction, I linked this databse with MS access file (which will be the interface, used by users). Users mainly use it for insertion, and I have somewhere else a SQL report server to retrieve some data and do some reports.

My issue now is that, I'm trying to find an easier way (without programming) to insert data in the intermediate table (Contact_Skill), other than getting the IDs manually. A thing like a drop down menu, that enables the user to choose the skill and it turns into its ID. Any easier way would be so welcomed as well. Thanks

Comment: If you want a solution without programming, best not to ask a programming Q&A site. See [su] for non-programming support.

Comment: You just need a form.  https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-form-in-Access-5d550a3d-92e1-4f38-9772-7e7e21e80c6b#createsubform

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, you likely don't need code, or at the very least VERY little code, and you certainly don't have to write code to insert the records.

So, I would create the form (bound directly to the  linked contact table.

So, you can use ctrl-f, or whatever to search, find, jump to your record you want to edit. (so built in search features will suffice for now).

In that form, you will drop in a sub form. (a continues form - multiple items would work nice here.

So, in that form you have this:

In this example, I have 
customers
Invoices
Invoice details

So, really, I have near example the same kind of setup. One master table (customers)
Then a child table of invoices.

And then for each invoice, we have details of the invoice.

So, your main form will have that sub form dropped in that shows the contact skills.

In my case, I have this:

[image]

So, for this, you not really written any code.

Now, do note that for each invoice (or your case of contact skills).

Note how I have a edit button in that continues form.

This allows our "drill" down.

The code behind this button is:

```
if me.Dirty = true, then me.Dirty = False
docmd.OpenForm "frmInvoice",,,"ID = " & me!id
```

So, clicking on edit will launch a new "main" form based on invoice (or in your case skills) the ONE record.

Now for that skills record, it not clear if you have another drill down (child table), but lets assume you do!

so, In that form, you simply drop in another sub form (again continues items), and you thus are now free to add more skills to that one contact skill.

In my case, it is invoice details, so we have this:

[image]

The above screens are rather crude (they are test scenes), but it shows a design in which you  dealing with 3 typical related tables.

So the whole system works with about 6 lines of code. Just keep in mind that when you drop in a sub form to relate child items? Access will setup the foreign key value that belongs to the parent table that has the one "main" record, and that sub-form of child records. All that is required is that the link master/child setting is setup correct. Once done, then Access will manage and set the correct values used to relate the tables to each other, and you don't have to write any SQL or even any code for that matter. (you are free to add a sub form record, and then hit Edit button for further details to edit, or as noted add more child records to that form you just launched.

So related tables, and adding of child records is VERY automatic in Access, and you don't write code to add the records - access will do all this work for you if you follow the above design pattern. About the only code you ever had to add is the the "edit" button to launch the next form in the sequence.